# How do I group by multiple parameters using CDbCriteria in Yii?

Tags: yii

Currently I have a criteria as shown below which finds average of column1 in my base table while joining with table1 and table2.

```
    $criteria= new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'AVG(t.column1) as cc';
    $criteria->group = 'table1.id';
    $criteria->with = array('table1', 'table2');
```

How do I group by tabel1.id as well as table2.id in the above criteria?

Comment: refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#group-detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seperate them by `,`

```
   $criteria->group = 'table1.id , table2.id';
```